# How to remove XML child having same name

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

Thanks for valuable replies.

I have two node having same name with different data. i want to remove one particular node instead of deleting two nodes. For example:

```
        <names> 
        <name>Apple</name> 
        <name>Ball</name>
        <name>Cat</name> 
        <name>Doll</name> 
        <name>Elephant</name> 
        </names>
```

In the above example there is 5 different names contains same node value. in that how to delete one particular node. i want to delete cat. Is this possible to do in DOM.?? pls guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the xml into a nodelist with dom and return a list, loop trough it programatically and remove what you want, before you write it back to the xml file.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any examples..??pls i am struck in this concept.

Comment: Thank you dude, i got rough idea. once i got the perfect solution i let you know the answer.